# No result returned from ActiveRecord execute_procedure() in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in my SQLServer database. The procedure does what it is supposed to do, but whenever I try to run it from my Ruby on Rails app, it executes the procedure, but I cannot get a return value. I have also tried modifying the procedure to use an output parameter.

```
@success = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("procedure",params[:field1],params[:field2],params[:field3])
render html: @success
```

The render shows an empty array. It should be a 1 if the procedure succeeds or a 0 if it fails. When I run this in SQL Server Management Studio, I can get the return value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rails-sqlserver-adapter/6C4sDXdtAfA. I need to run the procedure, then get the return from the raw connection as follows.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("procedure",params[:field1],params[:field2]
@success = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection_return_code
```

Comment: I believe it should be `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection.return_code` not `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection_return_code

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that `execute_procedure` returns an array — which is what you're looking for. What you want is the results. Maybe `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("procedure",params[:field1],params[:field2],params[:field3]).to_a`?

Hit `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("procedure",params[:field1],params[:field2],params[:field3]).inspect` to see what's going on, or you could see if `to_json` is implemented.

Lastly, `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute_procedure("procedure",params[:field1],params[:field2],params[:field3]).methods` will return what methods are available.

Comment: The source code for the method is here http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/3.2.9/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Sqlserver/DatabaseStatements:execute_procedure.

results is declared in this method as an empty array, and all the methods that the .methods gives seems to imply that it is an array. When I did the to_json, it shows an empty array also. I am looking for the 1 or 0 that the actual procedure returns.

Comment: what about `#result`, `#first` ?

Comment: Nothing from that either